# How do I change the spark.ui.port?

Tags: jetty, apache-spark

I am using spark-submit and tried to do this in the jar file with `.setExecutorEnv("spark.ui.port", "4050")` on the spark context, but it still tried to hit 4040. I then tried to put a `--conf spark.ui.port=4050` after `spark-submit` and before `--class CLASSNAME`, but that didn't work either, this time saying "Error: Unrecognized option '--conf'". How do I get around this? The actual error I'm running into is that there is an active spark server that others are using that is preventing this spark-submit from starting the jetty server. It's then not hitting up other ports, so I'm trying to force it to do that.

Comment: Which Spark version are you using?

Comment: Spark: 1.0.0, Hadoop: 2.3.0

Answer (score 21):

`--conf spark.ui.port=4050` is a Spark 1.1 feature. You can set it in your codes, such as:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(s"SimpleApp").set("spark.ui.port", "4050")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: What if you launch two application with the same vale for "spark.ui.port"? Will it fail?

Comment: No, the second app will fail to bind to 4050 and try 4051