# Change Java spark port number

Tags: java

My java spark web application using the embedded jetty web server uses port number 4567. Unfortunately this port number is blocked on my computer and don't wish to unblock it. If looked at the spark documentation but it doesn't contain how to change the port number of the embedded Jetty server to 8080.

Comment: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#port

Comment: This might be a dupe.  Have you checked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644114/change-jetty-default-port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the spark.ui.port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388332/how-do-i-change-the-spark-ui-port)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the port number in your java spark web application using the function `port()`. This has to be done before using routes and filters

official documentation link: http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#port

**Example**

```
port(8080);
// Routes of your endpoint...
```