# trying to set spark ui port to a range, but it keeps running on a random number

Tags: apache-spark

i try to set up the spark ui port to 35000 and max retry 200.
but when it runs, it doesn't use the 35xxx ports. it uses a random number ports.
i have tried both ways by changing the config and using code (according to [How do I change the spark.ui.port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388332/how-do-i-change-the-spark-ui-port))

does anyone have idea on this?

---

**here is the config spark-defaults.conf.j2:**

```
spark.master yarn
spark.port.maxRetries 200
spark.ui.port 35000
spark.blockManager.port 36000
spark.driver.blockManager.port 37000
spark.driver.port 38000
```

---

**here are the logs:**

```
-Dspark.ui.port=35000 
... 
INFO - Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://xxx.xxx:34138
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

> spark.ui.port=4040

as context settings :
under your *spark-job-server installation*/bin
file :

> settings.conf
> as :
>
> ```
> context-settings {
> num-cpu-cores = 4           # Number of cores to allocate.  Required.
> memory-per-node = 2g         # Executor memory per node, -Xmx style eg 
> spark.ui.port=4040
> }
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).